# Session and Thread in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET website where a thread is responible for doing some code retrived from a database queue.

Is it possible to get access to the Session or pass that as a parameter ?

My current code looks a follows:

```
MediaJob nextJob = GetNextJobFromDB();

CreateMedia media = new CreateMedia();

Thread t = new Thread(new parameterizedThreadStart(media.DOSTUFF);

t.Start(nextJob);
```

The HttpContext.Current.Session is null when running in a thread, so cant do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your job gets done outside the asp.net thread, then its probably not safe to assume that session would be available. Only deterministic way would be to pass this data explicitly to the thread. You can do this by assigning data in a [named data slot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.getnameddataslot.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

edited:

```
 HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
 Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    HttpContext.Current = ctx;
                    worker.DoWork();
                }));
 t.Start();
 // [... do other job ...]
 t.Join();
```

Comment: Author edited his answer to say that no, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is not available in the new thread.

Comment: The code in the answer matches the one here word for word. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925227/access-httpcontext-current-from-threads

Comment: The `Session` is still null inside the Thread, using this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the session from within a thread, but you could share your data using: `HttpRuntime.Cache`

There are a few things to keep in mind though: unlike session, cache do expire. Also the cache is shared between all web users.