# null reference error in task.run async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am using the following code for sign in in a web api. I get null reference exception on `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(authUser.UserId.ToString(), false);` 
call. Please guide me what I am doing wrong...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> SignIn(JObject credentails)
    {
        string returnVal = "";

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            string userName = (string)credentails.SelectToken("Username");
            string password = (string)credentails.SelectToken("Password");
            UserService userSvc = new UserService(new SqlConnection(_conStr));
            var authUser = userSvc.Authenticate(userName, password);
            if (authUser != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("DR_CLIENT_ID", authUser.DRClientId);
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("USER_ID", authUser.UserId);
                returnVal = authUser.FullName;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Invalid Credentials!"),
                    ReasonPhrase = "Error"
                });
            }
        });
        return returnVal;
    }
```

UPDATE-1
in this case no value is actually null as I can see it in the debug mode. but when I remove wait Task.Run(() = {}); block from this code, it works fine without any issue.

Comment: please re-consider as this question is not about null reference exception and is about main thread and background thread...

Comment: Okay. Next time, please make clear you checked all this. I was not able to tell from your question. Also, if there is one close voter, use @username to ping him.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` will be null inside the task, which is probably the reason for your NullReferenceException. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748267/using-httpcontext-in-async-task)

Comment: @DanielJ.G. it does not seems to be null in debug mode.

Comment: FYI no body seemed to have addressed the elephant in the room .

Why would you use Task.Run for this in the first place. even if you were not using SetAuthCookie you will still wan't your web app to be I/O bound. 

UserService which reaches out to be DB should be in implemented in an asynchronous manner and nothing else in that code has any reason to be done on another thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `Task.Run`. In ASP.NET, when an incoming request arrives, it assigns a thread pool thread to handle that request, and this thread runs your code. What your code then does is use `Task.Run` to move to *another* thread pool thread *without* a request context, and then assumes it has a request context. `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` (and `HttpContext.Current`) will simply not work without a request context.

To resolve this, remove the call to `Task.Run`. You should (almost) never use `Task.Run` on ASP.NET.