# Autofac and resolving services in legacy Web Forms in Tasks

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have **legacy** `Web Forms` application with `Web Api 2`. I installed `Autofac` to get some little help of DI.

Implemented `IContainerProviderAccessor` on `Global.asax` and registered all I need.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Provider that holds the application container.
/// </summary>
static IContainerProvider s_containerProvider;

/// <summary>
/// Instance property that will be used by Autofac HttpModules to resolve and inject dependencies.
/// </summary>
public IContainerProvider ContainerProvider
{
    get { return s_containerProvider; }
}

// Build up your application container and register your dependencies.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
AutofacBootstraper.RegisterDependencies(builder);

// Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
var container = builder.Build();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

// Once you're done registering things, set the container provider up with your registrations.
s_containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(container);
```

It works in controllers etc.

But I want to resolve my services in other parts in application. Not just in controllers.

In some classes I was able to use `Resolve` in pattern

```cs
var cpa = ((IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance);
var scope = cpa.ContainerProvider.RequestLifetime;
_myFacade = scope.Resolve<IMyFacade>();
```

So I used `HttpContext`.

But in other parts I'm using parallel procesing and tasks. For example

```cs
public class MyController : ApiControllerBase
{

    public IHttpActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        _myFacade.DoSomething();
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class MyFacade : IMyFacade
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DoSomethingInTask()
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Well, now I want to use the same resolve pattern as before in method `DoSomethingInTask`, but of course there is no `HttpRequest`, so is is not possible. Different task, different scope etc.

Is there any way how to get `Autofac container` and call `Resolve<>` anywhere? Maybe using `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way how to get Autofac container and call Resolve<> anywhere?

yes.it's in the office doc in the Manual Property Injection section,but you can use the container for resolving.

official doc:https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html#manual-property-injection

```
var container=(Autofac.Integration.Web.IContainerProviderAccessor) HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
var myService=container.ContainerProvider.ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IMyService>();
myService.SomeMethod(....)
```

> but of course there is no HttpRequest

yes, but you can get the httpcontext:
[Using HttpContext in Async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748267/using-httpcontext-in-async-task)