# How to run a statement on the main thread from a task

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, task

I create a task as below:

```
ExportTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ExcelExport(rs, ReportCenter));
```

Inside the ExcelExport() method I like to run a statement that will save an excel spreadsheet, but it needs to be on the main thread:

```
workbook.SaveAs(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AppSettingsUtils.GetString("ExportExcelFileName")) ? "Export.xlsx" : AppSettingsUtils.GetString("ExportExcelFileName"), Response, ExcelDownloadType.PromptDialog, ExcelHttpContentType.Excel2013);
```

For that matter I'm curious on how to get a value from a statement such as this in a task as well:

```
ReportCenter = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("ReportCenter");
```

Seems to be a lot of info on windows forms but having trouble finding for web forms.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: For getting access to `HttpContext` see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662456/how-do-i-access-httpcontext-current-in-task-factory-startnew

Comment: Also files can be saved on the background thread as well, any need for it to be on main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Task.Factory.Start` will fire up a new `Thread` and because the
>   `HttpContext.Context` is local to a `thread` it won't be automaticly
>   copied to the new Thread, so you need to pass it by hand:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    state =>
        {
            var context = (HttpContext) state;
            //use context
        },
    HttpContext.Current);
```