# How to setup Request.Header in FakeHttpContext for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, httpcontext

I have a **FakeHttpContext** I have been trying to modify to include some headers for testing purposes

```
public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
{
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://stackoverflow/", "");
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
    var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);   

    var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                    new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
                                                    HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                                    SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

    httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof(HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                        null, CallingConventions.Standard,
                                        new[] { typeof(HttpSessionStateContainer) },
                                        null)
                                .Invoke(new object[] { sessionContainer });

    return httpContext;
 }
```

This works without the headers but when I add any of these lines of code in between the **httpRequest** and **stringWriter** lines.

```
    httpRequest.Headers.Add("blah", "1234");
    httpRequest.Headers["blah"] = "1234";
```

It throws

> An exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred
>   in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

- Why am I getting that exception?
- Is there a possible way to add headers to **HttpContext** for testing
  **WebApi controllers**?

Comment: If you can get your code to work with HttpContextBase, then you can usually mock things like this (including the request, and the request headers). Generally, that shouldn't be a problem as long as you aren't using HttpContext.Current.

Comment: I tried following the answers on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640/mocking-asp-net-mvc-controller-context but it seems not to work with WebAPI controllers but MVC controllers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just discovered that with **HttpRequestMessage class**, you can easily add headers for testing your **WebAPI controllers** without having to create any **fake** **HttpContext**.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://stackoverflow");
request.Headers.Add("deviceId","1234");
_myController.Request = request;
```

Comment: `Property or indexer 'ControllerBase.Request' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` :-(

Comment: Doesn't work in my case

Comment: @OliverPearmain Microsoft changed the way WebAPI Controllers work in later versions and that's why it's not working. The solution is specifically for .Net 4.5 sorry that wasn't clear in the answer or post. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.request?view=aspnet-webapi-5.2#system-web-http-apicontroller-request

Answer (score 23):

I'm using .Net Core 3.1 and the Moq framework. I created a DefaultHttpContext, set the headers there, finally assigned it to the controller ControllerContext constructor.

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Headers["X-Example"] = "test-header";
var controller = new ExampleController(mockClient.Object, mockLogger.Object) 
{ 
    ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
    {
        HttpContext = httpContext
    }
};
```

Source: https://www.thecodebuzz.com/unit-test-mock-httprequest-in-asp-net-core-controller/

Comment: This one worked great for me, Controller.Request was readonly (.net cor 5) not sure if I missed something.

Comment: please provide the code for the setup of DefaultHttpContext class

Comment: It works like a charm ! thaks @DMendonza

Comment: @ayushmishra The DefaultHttpContext class is part of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace. Here's the link to Microsoft's documentation on it:
[DefaultHttpContext Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.defaulthttpcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Great solution for net core 3.1