# c# asp.net - How to find current page URL while in a different thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find my URL, while i am in a different thread, is it possible ?
my code : 
`string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

the error i am getting is "threw an exception of type nullreference exception"

Comment: What's "a different trade"?

Comment: you mean "thread" by saying "trade"?

Comment: you should check is null. like use ?.  `var url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current?.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: it is null but i would like to find the url

Comment: I think your question not correct but try write 
`string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`

Comment: do you mean string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; because this is my code but because i am in a different threadi cant access the HttpContext.Current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access HttpContext.Current unless you set it by passing a reference into your new thread see the answer to this question for more details

[Access HttpContext.Current from different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925227/access-httpcontext-current-from-different-threads)