# Method timeout without creating new thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How I can implement timeout for a block of code in asp.net application without using `Task` or `Thread`? I don't want create new threads because `HttpContext` will be `NULL` in another threads.

For example, following code will not work

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var test = MethodWithContext();
});
if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
    throw new Exception("Timeout");

object MethodWithContext()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Items["Test"]; // <--- HttpContext is NULL
}
```

## EDIT:

I don't want pass current context to method, because I will have a lot of nested methods inside method... so a lot of refactor must be done for this solution

## EDIT2:

I have realized that I can assign current context to variable before creating new task and replace `HttpContext` in task with this variable. This will be safe?

```
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        HttpContext.Current = ctx;
        var test = MethodWithContext();
    });
    if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
        throw new Exception("Timeout");

    object MethodWithContext()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Items["Test"]; // now works correctly
    }
```

Comment: Why do you not want to create a Task for this?

Comment: Why do you need HttpContext in worker threads? Just pass all needed info and they wont need any other "context"

Comment: @Szer yes, this example is very simple, but in situation when many nested methods uses HttpContext, it may be difficult to refactor the code

Comment: Would [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8925227/728795) help?

Comment: @Andrei It looks like my code from #EDIT2 section. Looks like it works with this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to pass the context of you main thread like this:

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Takes the context of you current thread an passes it to the other thread.
    var test = MethodWithContext(HttpContext.Current);
});

if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
    throw new Exception("Timeout");

void object MethodWithContext(HttpContext ctx)
{
    // Now we are operating on the context of you main thread.
    return ctx.Items["Test"];
}
```

But the question is still:
**Why do you want to create a task for this?**
After starting the task you are simply waiting for its completion. You could just call your method synchronously. Although I am not sure how to limit the execution to 5 seconds if you do that.

---

As you have mentioned in the comments you'd like to get rid of the additional parameter because you have more than one method. This is how I'd do it:

```
public void YourOriginalMethod()
{
   YourUtilityClass util = new YourUtilityClass(HttpContext.Current);

   var task = Task.Run(() =>
   {
       var test = util.MethodWithContext();
   });

   if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
       throw new Exception("Timeout");
 }



public class YourUtilityClass
{
    private readonly HttpContext _ctx;

    public YourUtilityClass(HttpContext ctx)
    {
       if(ctx == null)
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ctx));

       _ctx = ctx;
    }



    public void object MethodWithContext()
    {
       return _ctx.Items["Test"];
    }


    // You can add more methods here...
}
```

Comment: Can I avoid passing context to method? I mean situation when I have many methods in block and another methods nested in these methods

Comment: @mkul Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Or maybe just assign context to variable before execute `Task.Run()`, and inside `Task.Run` replace current context? It will safe?

`var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
                                    var task = Task.Run(() =>
                                    {
                                        HttpContext.Current = ctx;
                                        var test = MethodWithContext() }`

Comment: @mkul Sure, but that's a detail. You asked to solve the problem that your program doesn't work.