# MVC 5 Render Razor View Async

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented rendering a Razor view to a string, according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/6237687

But my problem is that it takes some time to render the view, and it blocks the thread, so I want to call it asynchronously.

I found that Asp.Net Core has **"RenderAsync()"**, but it does not seem to be in MVC 5...

So, my question is how can I call the **"Render()"** method asynchronously, like in Asp.Net Core?

My rendering function:

```
    private string RenderViewToString(string viewPath, object model)
    {
        // Finds the ViewEngine for this view:
        ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(Context, viewPath, null);
        if (viewEngineResult == null)
        {
            viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(Context, viewPath);
            if (viewEngineResult == null)
                throw new FileNotFoundException("View: \"" + viewPath + "\" cannot be found.");
        }

        // Gets the view, and attaches the model to the view data:
        IView view = viewEngineResult.View;
        Context.Controller.ViewData = this.ViewData;
        Context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

        // Renders the view:
        string result = null;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var ctx = new ViewContext(Context, view, Context.Controller.ViewData, Context.Controller.TempData, sw);
            view.Render(ctx, sw);
            result = sw.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Problem is in: **"view.Render(ctx, sw);"**

Comment: Are you just trying not to block or are you trying to gain resources, if you're trying not to block just use Task.Run()

Comment: @johnny5 - I'm trying not to block, I get exceptions when I use Task.Run() because the context is not available anymore...

Comment: can't you pass the context in?

Comment: @johnny5 - When I pass the context, I get: System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'

Comment: are you just passing it in or assigning it see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19319205/1938988)

Comment: @johnny5 - I'm assigning it, and I still get that exception...

Comment: where do you get the error? what function etc. post details